# C++ Builder 10.4 and Tinyxml

Tags: c++, c++builder, tinyxml2

Good evening,
I try to use tinyxml 2 with my C++ builder IDE. The code is really simple. I only want to parse an existing XML-File. The Code looks like this:

```
#include "tinyxml2.h"
using namespace tinyxml2;

class myclass
{
  XMLDocument doc_;
}
```

And now the compiler gives the messages: "reference to XMLDocument is ambiguous"

Any ideas? I don't know how to fix this. Thank you very much for your tipps.

Comment: there's a semicolon missing at the end of the file. Not sure though if this fixes anything.

Comment: Don't do `using namespace tinyxml2;` in your header file. Instead, type it out `tinyxml2::XMLDocument doc_;`

Comment: I tried this too. But then i receive an error from the linker.

Comment: That's better so keep it like that. You probably don't link with the `tinyxml2` library.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue in 10.3.3.
Have you tried a project with just xmltest.cpp and tinyxml2.cpp ?
This compiles and runs in 10.3.3 for both Win32 and Win64.
Creating a second project with your code plus the missing semicolon, plus main, also compiled and ran.

Comment: If I don't prefix the `XMLDocument` with the `tinyxml2` prefix then I also get the ambiguous calls because it does not know which of the classes to use. So that should help and did you try a full compile? Try a test console project to reproduce.